# Find launch template based on tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, jq

I'm trying to get the launch template VersionNumber based on the deployment_version tag.

```
aws ec2 describe-launch-template-versions --launch-template-id lt-1234
```

Will return something like

```
{
    "LaunchTemplateVersions": [
        {
            "LaunchTemplateId": "lt-1234",
            "LaunchTemplateName": "api",
            "VersionNumber": 16,
            "LaunchTemplateData": {
                "TagSpecifications": [
                    {
                        "ResourceType": "instance",
                        "Tags": [
                            {
                                "Key": "deployment_version",
                                "Value": "release/6.1"
                            },
                            {
                                "Key": "server_type",
                                "Value": "api"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "LaunchTemplateId": "lt-1234",
            "LaunchTemplateName": "api",
            "VersionNumber": 15,
            "LaunchTemplateData": {
                "TagSpecifications": [
                    {
                        "ResourceType": "instance",
                        "Tags": [
                            {
                                "Key": "deployment_version",
                                "Value": "release/5.7"
                            },
                            {
                                "Key": "server_type",
                                "Value": "api"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried using jq building something like this

```
aws ec2 describe-launch-template-versions --launch-template-id lt-1234 | jq '.LaunchTemplateVersions[] | select(.LaunchTemplateData.TagSpecifications.Tags[].Value=="release/6.1")'
```

But it doesn't work, with error:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:848): Cannot index array with string "Tags"
```

Most of the jq select examples I could find were made for single level object, does anyone know how to return VersionNumber (16) baes on the tag value (release/6.1) using the example data from above?

Comment: How do you want to handle multiple `TagSpecification` elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
aws ec2 describe-launch-template-versions --launch-template-id lt-1234 | jq '.LaunchTemplateVersions[] | select(.LaunchTemplateData.TagSpecifications[].Tags[] | select(.Key == "deployment_version" and .Value == "release/6.1")) | .VersionNumber'
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: Note that this solution will produce duplicated version number outputs if you have more than a single tag specification.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what you want to happen when there are several elements in the `TagSpecifications` array (I assume there can be different resource types). If you want to get a stream of all version numbers if *any* tag specification matches, you could use the following, leveraging the fact that the `Tags` array can be converted to an object:

```
.LaunchTemplateVersions[]
| select(any(.LaunchTemplateData.TagSpecifications[].Tags|from_entries; .deployment_version == "release/6.1"))
| .VersionNumber
```

[`to_entries`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#to_entries,from_entries,with_entries) will convert arrays such as `[{"Key":"a", "Value":1}, {"Key":"b", "Value":2}]` into objects (`{"a":1, "b":2}` for this example).

If you are only interested in the first tag, the `select` becomes:

```
select(.LaunchTemplateData.TagSpecifications[0].Tags|from_entries.deployment_version == "release/6.1")
```

Since your sample input only contains a single specification, the output is the same for both:

```
16
```

If you need valid JSON as output, you have to produce an array. To do that, replace the pattern `.x[] | select(f) | g` with `.x | map(select(f) | g)`. This should output `[16]`.

But there might be other solutions that are a better fit for you. Maybe you are only interested in tag specifications of type "instance" (and there will be only a single item with that type)?